# Solution for periodic surveys

Tags: workflow, list, survey-list, tasks

I have a list (Account Exec Distribution List) in SharePoint 2007 that provides the Client Name and the associated Account Exec (AE). The AE team would like to complete a survey of sorts that will provide senior management with a feel for the health of each account. This survey of sorts will be either monthly or quarterly.  I have considered using the Survey in SharePoint but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to create hundreds of surveys (one for each client) by Account Exec and getting them to automatically generate every month/quarter.  I've also considered creating a list/spreadsheet that the AE could complete.  However, I also need some way to track progress.  Does anyone know of an efficient way to create tasks from data in a list or imported spreadsheet (Account Exec Distribution Report)?  I'm also interested in any thoughts regarding a good approach for collecting the answers to 5-6 questions that ultimately will guage the health of a client account. I can utilize SPD or OOTB SharePoint to accomplish this.

Comment: Hi Rich,
I have some ideas in mind that I'd like to share with you. But maybe you like to give us a little more insight in what you actually need. 

Like: 
- What are your requirements regarding "process tracking"? 
- Do you need some sort of automatition (workflows, etc)? 
- Do you need a visual KPI that is (somehow) calculated? 

All that infomation will help to find the right solution. But -as always- the more requirements you have, the more complex the solution has to be.

Comment: My goal is to gather the answers to 5 - 6 questions for each client/account from the Account Exec (AE) and store the answers for reporting purposes. Each AE will have 35 to 50 accounts each to assess. This process must be repeated quarterly. No KPI is needed. I do need the ability to see where the AE is in completing the Account health assessment (in progress or completed) and the results to create reports/views from.  I want to keep the solution as simple as possible but effective. 80/20 rule applies.  This is something I would like to accomplish within a couple weeks or less.  Rich

Answer (score 1):

The very, very easiest approch I see would be like this:

- You create a new document library called "AE Surveys"
- You might to enable versioning, depending on your needs
- You create a new content type called "AE Survey"
- You add a column "AE name" to the library (maybe a dropdown)
- You add a column "Month" and "Year" to the library
- You create a view that is grouped by "AE name" and then grouped by "Year". Sorted by Month.
- You attach a new document tempate (I suggest Excel) to that content type, which looks like this:

---

AE Name

..................Question 1......Question 2...... Question n.....

Account 1

Account 2

Account n

---

When a AE comes to that document library the first time, he clicks "New" to add a new survey. He will then have to enter his accounts to the "Account" column in Excel (replacing the "Account 1", "Account 2", "Account n" with actual Account names). 
He will then answer the questions and save the documents with proper metadata (AE name, Year, Month). The next time he has to do the survey he OPEN THE EXISTING one and just updates the answer to the question as well as the metadata (Month and Year only).

Comment: As I mentioned, this is a very basic solution. You might extend it with tasks, workflows, KPI's and other features later.